# Is the random number analiser software reliable for performing Nist 800_22 test

Tags: random-number-generator, nist

I am working on generating pseudo random numbers from a chaotic oscillator's signal. In literature I have read about the Nist 800-22 test used for checking randomness. I friend gave me a software "random number analyzer to use for this test. Has any one ever used this software before? Is it reliable?
If not, what recommendations can you please give me as far as NIST 800-22 test is concerned?

Comment: A NIST 800-22 test (or perhaps whatever that insufficiently specified "Random Number Analyzer" is) can be helpful to demonstrate that a noise source + conditionning is UNsuitable for cryptographic use. Alone, it can't be a useful indication of the contrary (that the thing is suitable for cryptographic use). For this, we need to analyze the structure of the generator, including it's source and post-conditioning, and perhaps it's so-called _online test_, which objective is to catch failure of the source and put the application in a fail-safe mode.